# How do I select individual elements of a given (very large) matrix, see if they are in a particular range and change them in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, range, element, pi

I have a matrix which is 256x938. I need to go through each individual element, see if it is in the range -pi < element < pi, if it is not then we need to subtract or add a multiple of 2*pi to get the element in the range. Preferrably without for loops as we have found that they are very inefficient.

Comment: Actually, 256x938 is not "very large" by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 4):

Not unlike the other solutions posed, but a bit cleaner since it requires only one simple line of code...

```
B = mod(A+pi,2*pi) - pi;

A = -20:2:20;
mod(A+pi,2*pi) - pi
ans =
  Columns 1 through 12
 -1.1504  0.84956 2.8496 -1.4336  0.56637 2.5664 -1.7168  0.28319 2.2832   -2   0  2

  Columns 13 through 21
 -2.2832 -0.28319 1.7168 -2.5664 -0.56637 1.4336 -2.8496 -0.84956 1.1504
```

Comment: Very neat, but I'm afraid this fails with numbers more than 2*pi less than -pi. For example, set `A = -20`. This solution yields `B = -7.4336`, which is most definitely not in the range -pi < B < pi.

Comment: @ColinTBowers - Trivially fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
B=rem(A,2*pi)
B(A<-pi)=A(A<-pi)+2*pi
B(A>pi)=A(A>pi)-2*pi
```

Every element `b` in `B` is now `-pi <= b <= pi`.

It can not become `-pi < b < pi` as asked for in the question.

Comment: I don't think this is quite general enough. It will fail if an element is more than 2*pi from the required range. The OP stated that you may need to subtract or add a *multiple* of 2*pi.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Matlab at hand right now, so my suggestion might not work, but I hope the idea will.

Try something along this way:

```
c = cos(B); % will set all your elements between [-1 1]
B2 = acos(c);  % will return values between [0 PI] but for some the sign will be wrong
B2 = B2.*sign(sin(B)); % should set the correct sign for each element.
```

Hope this works.

I could have condensed all three lines to 1, but I tried to make the idea as clear as possible.

Comment: for values equal to PI the last line will zero the result, but if you check for c==-1 you could make a final correction for those values by setting them to PI in B2.